# Battling Nemesis

Tags: bravely-default

I just wanted to know if your consumables get used up the same as in the main game? I have a couple level 25 Nemesis' in my village and I don't want to just take them on as I am only around level 9 right now.  I'd rather not burn a lot of consumable items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all consumable items you use in Nemesis battles are actually consumed. You will also keep any damage not healed before the end of the battle, and any KO's will stay that way.

These battles are treated as though you were fighting them where you stand in the main game.